# WooCommerce exclude certain product attributes from shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, storefront

I've been wracking my brain on this one. Currently, to display all custom product attributes on the shop page (not to be confused with the product page) I'm using:

```
function show_attr() {
   global $product;
   echo '<div class="attributes">';
   $product->list_attributes();
   echo'</div>'
}
```

This works just fine, and displays all product attributes, but I only want to include certain ones. I have also tried following [this person's](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-list_attributes-exclude-attribute-term/) advice:

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :
    if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || 'CSC Credit' == $attribute['name'] || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) ) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $has_row = true;
    }
?>
```

So that unfortunately did not work either. I was able to remove the desired attribute, but it removes it on EVERY page, and I want to exclude it ***only*** from the shop page.

I see that the $attribute variable has this `[is_visible]` condition. Does anyone have any ideas of how I might remove that for specific attributes on the shop page? I'm at a total loss. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you can control the attributes for any give product via the [`woocommerce_get_product_attributes`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/481471a64cccc97ffd084166f17ecf399dbd4ff3/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1401) filter. The `$attributes` passing through this filter are in an associative array of arrays. with the attribute's "slug" as the array key. As an example a `var_dump()` might reveal the following `$attributes`.

```
array (size=1)
  'pa_color' => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string 'pa_color' (length=8)
      'value' => string '' (length=0)
      'position' => string '0' (length=1)
      'is_visible' => int 0
      'is_variation' => int 1
      'is_taxonomy' => int 1
```

If the attribute is a taxonomy, the slug will be prefaced with "pa_" which I've always assumed stood for product attribute. An attribute that is not a taxonomy will just have it's name for the slug, ex: "size".

Using [WooCommerce Conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) you can specifically target the attributes *only* on the shop page.

Here are two example filters, the first is for excluding a specific attribute:

```
// Exclude a certain product attribute on the shop page
function so_39753734_remove_attributes( $attributes ) {

    if( is_shop() ){
        if( isset( $attributes['pa_color'] ) ){
            unset( $attributes['pa_color'] );
        }
    }

    return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_attributes', 'so_39753734_remove_attributes' );
```

And the latter is for building up a custom list of attributes based on attributes you do wish to include.

```
// Include only a certain product attribute on the shop page
function so_39753734_filter_attributes( $attributes ) {

    if( is_shop() ){
        $new_attributes = array();

        if( isset( $attributes['pa_color'] ) ){
            $new_attributes['pa_color'] = $attributes['pa_color'] ;
        }

        $attributes = $new_attributes;

    }

    return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_attributes', 'so_39753734_filter_attributes' );
```

**Updated** Mar 29, 2018 with `woocommerce_product_get_attributes` since `woocommerce_get_product_attributes` is deprecated.

Comment: Ah wonderful! This makes so much more sense with the examples. Thanks for taking the time to explain further. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Bad news recently: woocommerce_get_product_attributes is deprecated

Comment: The replacement is `woocommerce_product_get_attributes`. Otherwise, I think it should stay the same, but don't have time to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<?php
if (is_page('shop')) {
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :
        if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || 'CSC Credit' == $attribute['name'] || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $has_row = true;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1! I just left work, but will try this ASAP in the morning. I can't believe I didn't think of this. I'm new to Wordpress, so everything's coming at me all at once. Will accept the answer tomorrow once I get this up and swinging. Thanks for your prompt response! :)

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: I was going to answer that you need to use `is_shop()`. I think you could also filter `woocommerce_get_product_attributes` in lieu of writing your own loop.