# WooCommerce Hiding a specific custom attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I've seen multiple answers to how to move or remove all custom attributes and there is documentation on how to remove boilerplate attributes like dimension and SKU, but I still can't seem to find a snippet, filter or hook detailing how to go about removing a single specific "custom" attribute.

In our case, the custom attribute we have in use is useful for backend reasons, but we'd rather not show it on the frontend. I'm aware of the tick-box in product data for attributes while in admin making an attribute not visible, but I'm handling over 2,000 products...it just wouldn't be a practical approach to tick it for each one.

(EDIT)
I was finally able to source an example on how to do this.
@helgatheviking hit upon the [base of coding needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753734/woocommerce-exclude-certain-product-attributes-from-shop-page?rq=1) to make this happen.

```
function my_attribute_hider ( $attributes ) {
if ( isset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] ) ){
    unset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] );
}
return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_product_attributes', 'my_attribute_hider' );
```

Be sure to replace **attribute-name** w/ your attribute's unique slug.

Comment: Consider adding an answer for your own question as your solution works well.

Answer (score 1):

I almost missed the answer that I was looking for because the author has posted it on the question post itself. So I am posting it here.

```
function my_attribute_hider ( $attributes ) {
if ( isset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] ) ){
    unset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] );
}
return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_product_attributes', 'my_attribute_hider' );
```

Note: It will not remove the attribute itself, it will just hide it from the product pages. It will just ignore it.